# How can I add an image to a comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, images, uploader

When I comment on an answer to the question, I need to add an image to show more clearly about my resolving.

How can I add an image to a comment?

Comment: In a comment. i cannot find 'add picture' button.

Comment: You can't add images to comments. You can add image links... Your question doesn't say anything about comments. Can you please [edit] your question to explain what you're trying to do in more detail.

Comment: I need to upload image into StackExchange for get the LINK.

Comment: So upload it in the answer box and then just grab the link without ever submitting the answer. But why are you putting the information in the comments instead of in the post?

Comment: Add image into comment
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOWXw.jpg)

Comment: But it not show.

Comment: Nope. I already explained that you can't add images to comments. You can only add image links. This is by design and will not be changed any time soon.

Comment: To note, if adding images to comments was allowed, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYOct.png) can happen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't add images to comments (in a way that they actually show as images). You can add image links, though. If the image is already on the web somewhere, just post the link to it. If you have the image on your computer, upload the image in an answer field using the image uploader, copy the link to the image from the answer (**do not submit the answer**) and then paste it into the comment.

You can leave the links bare or hide them behind markdown and show just an image description

> `[Image description](imageURL)`